# Using data to create excel sheet

Tags: apache-poi, guava-table

I have a requirement in a web application to show a certain number of steps with a planned start and end time associated with each step.

These steps are read from an excel sheet , which is stored in db in binary format. Once I display the excel using Apache POI and Guava table(as seen in screenshot), I need to be able to capture the actual start and end time corresponding to each step. Using these actual times I need to create a replica of the initial sheet  putting in actual times.

Now I do not want to store the details in DB corresponding to each step, but thinking of any object like say a map storing key as task number and value as a combination of start and end time.

My only concern is how to persist this object among different sessions. Any advice on better alternative?

[image]

Comment: "How to persist an object among different sessions": Serializing the object - saving the serialized bytes somewhere - if needed reading the serialized bytes and de-serialize the object from them. | Any advice on better alternative? Store what you need in the DB ;-).

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks for a prompt reply! Looks like DB is the way out, makes sense. However, considering the fact that I would need to store a lot of objects in DB, was exploring an alternative to store in a temp object that I could do away later. Between sessions though, persistence is the way! Would have to look at Guava table serialisation. Thanks again!